# Error of a fit by a non-linear function

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I fit a set of experimental data (Xi,Yi) by a relatively complicated function, which depends on one parameter, f(X;C) minimizing the square deviation. How can I determine the error of the parameter C in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your fitting (I presume nonlinear least squares) software return the variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of your fit? 
If so, $\rm{s.e.}(C) = \sqrt{\frac{RSS}{\nu} * \Sigma_{1, 1}}$